# The number of sequences

Tags: probability

The number of  sequences that have five letters $A$ and three letters $B$ and two letters $C$ such that the first appearance of the letter $A$ is before  the first appearance of the letter $B$ ?
My attempt:
[image]

Comment: What are your thoughts on this?

Comment: @Thomas i actually solved the problem but not sure if it is right : http://www.arab4load.info/uploads/02_131362253602211.png

Comment: Welcome to MSE! While linking pictures is acceptable, the preferred way to ask a question is using MathJax. For future questions or answer, you might find [this tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) of interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: Ignore the $C$’s for a moment and think about the possible arrangements of the $A$’s and $B$’s: that string of $8$ letters **must** start with an $A$.

- How many strings of $5$ $A$’s and $3$ $B$’s start with $A$?
- How many ways are there to insert $2$ $C$’s into a string of $8$ letters?
- What must you do with these two numbers to finish off the problem?

**Added:** Yes, your solution is correct, if not the easiest one.